# Cannot clear items for ASP:Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

This is how I initiate my ASP:Repeater:

```
var taskItemsList = new List<Task>(); 

taskItemsList = GenerateActiveList(); //generates 6 items
_taskItemsListSorted = from Task in taskItemsList
                       orderby Task.AssignedTo ascending , Task.DueDateTicks ascending
                       select Task;
taskRepeater.DataSource = _taskItemsListSorted;
taskRepeater.DataBind();
```

This is how I try to make the same repeater display a different list (this code runs when user clicks a button):

```
taskRepeater.DataSource = null; taskRepeater.DataBind();

var taskItemsList = new List<Task>(); 

taskItemsList = GenerateInactiveList(); //generates 5 items
_taskItemsListSorted = from Task in taskItemsList
                       orderby Task.AssignedTo ascending , Task.DueDateTicks ascending
                       select Task;
taskRepeater.DataSource = _taskItemsListSorted;
taskRepeater.DataBind();
```

(Note in the second code section that a new function is used to generate a different list.)

The problem is that the Repeater control seems to still contain the items from the first code section.

The last action in section 2, taskRepeater.DataBind();, makes the ItemDataBound function fire 11 times which indicates the initially generated list items are still contained in the repeater somehow.

Any ideas of where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Most probably section 1st code is being called before (on page load I guess) the code in section 2nd of button click.

Comment: That is correct, yogi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only issue you have is that the OnClick event is firing up, doing what you want to do, but afterwards the page OnLoad is firing up and replacing the contents with the original one. To fix that, just do that on the page OnLoad:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    // Bind the repeater
```

Comment: Correct, this is the action I used to fix this issue.

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling section 2 code just do this,

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    taskRepeater.DataSource = dt;
    taskRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem. I believe the problem is that the Page_Load function fires when I click a button. Im trying to solve that with postback checks.